# Call detectChanges in angular zone

Tags: angular

When working outside of the angular zone, there are two ways to detect the changes - by reentering the zone with *NgZone.run* or with the *ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges* method. The *NgZone.run* method performs application tick which may cause performance issues because it rechecks the entire application. Calling *detectChanges* updates only the component view which is what I need, but if the component is rendering some content that it does not control and that depends on being initialized in the angular zone, it stops working. I created an example to demonstrate the case:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zv5mf1?file=src/app/resize.component.ts

Clicking the button initially updates the view. After resizing the window the button no longer updates the view because the click handler is not bound in the angular zone and does not trigger the change detection.

My question is - is there a way to detect changes only in the component view and initialize the content in the angular zone. In other words, specify that the current zone is the angular one without triggering application tick.

Comment: Your example is great to show the issue, but could you explain what you want to achieve precisely ? Because if it's that, I can just tell you that it's not how you bind an event in Angular ... Maybe having your goal would allow us to give you a workaround on this issue !

Comment: My goal is to detect changes only in the component view and for the button clicks to trigger the change detection. You have to bind the event this way if you don't want to run the change detection for the entire application each time the event is triggered. Something that can be very costly in terms of performance for more complex applications.

Comment: What you're saying isn't true, I provided an answer showing you how to do it (since you took your time to respond). Feel free to look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Several solutions.

The first one is to use the event manager : [**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zv5mf1-favaiz?file=src/app/resize.component.ts)

```
this.manager.addGlobalEventListener('window', 'resize', this.setCurrent.bind(this));
```

The second one is the `HostListener` decorator : [**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zv5mf1-5dhybl?file=src/app/resize.component.ts)

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event']) private setCurrent(): void {
```

The third and last one is template binding on global target : [**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zv5mf1-cfxap1?file=src/app/resize.component.ts)

```
template: ` <span [style.display]="'none'" (window:resize)="setCurrent()"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately all of the proposed solutions trigger application wide check each time the resize event is triggered. This can be seem if you add ngAfterViewChecked hook to the AppComponent:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zv5mf1-qhtz7e?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: This is how Angular works. Proof on **[this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zv5mf1-c11jra?file=src/app/resize.component.ts)** (click on the button to change the value).